# Problema Mandando Objeto asincrónico mediante emit de socket.io

Tags: javascript, promesas, socket.io

trataré de ser lo mas breve y objetivo posible, tengo un listado de productos en un .JSON y un servidor montado con express, es codigo muy sencillo para una entrega de un curso. La idea es que cuando el JSON sufra alguna modificacion (tengo un watcher de chokidar corriendo) mande el listado de productos usando emit de socket.io, y poder mostrarlo en el HTML con innerHTML. Para la parte de plantillas del html estoy usando handlebar.

Esto sería del lado del client

```
ws.on('connect', () => { 
    ws.emit('event_cl01', 'Este es el primer mensaje desde el cliente 01');
    const valorHTML = document.querySelector('#valor');
    ws.on('server_confirm', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg)
    });

    ws.on('socketProds', (prods) => { //Este prods sería el array de objetos, que no logro poder ver desde el HTML ya que es asincrónico
        console.log(prods) 
    })

})
```

Luego tenemos del lado del servidor..

```
    //socket.emit('socketProds',manager.getProducts())
socket.emit('socketProds',manager.getElements()) //Abajo explico que retorna este metodo de clase
```

El método manager.getElements() retorna un array de objetos de la siguiente forma:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Nafta Super","description":"Nafta economica con 85 octanos","price":212,"thumbnail":"super.png","code":"super","stock":500000,"status":true,"category":"fuels"},{"id":2,"title":"Nafta Premium","description":"Nafta Premium con 92 octanos","price":280,"thumbnail":"premium.png","code":"infinia","stock":500000,"status":true,"category":"fuels"},{"id":3,"title":"Gasoil","description":"Gasoil comun con azufre","price":180,"thumbnail":"gasoil.png","code":"gasoil","stock":500000,"status":true,"category":"fuels"},{"id":4,"title":"Diesel Premium","description":"Diesel Premium sin azufre","price":292,"thumbnail":"diesel.png","code":"euro","stock":500000,"status":true,"category":"fuels"},{"id":7,"title":"Elaion F30","description":"Aceite semisintetico x 1L","price":"5500","code":"F30","stock":"500","status":"true","category":"oils","thumbnail":"none"},{"id":8,"title":"Elaion F50","description":"1L","price":"6500","code":"F50","stock":"500","status":"true","category":"oils","thumbnail":"none"}]
```

De esta manera, yo del lado del cliente, en el HTML veo un objeto en la consola, el cual no puedo ver su contenido.. Si yo en lugar de mandar por el emit el manager.getElements(), mando un objeto sencillo: {nombre:"Carlos"} si lo puedo ver desde el HTML si acceso al objeto.nombre.. El problema evidentemente es una cuestion de asincronía, pero no logro darme cuenta como armar la promesa para verlo del lado cliente..
Seria muy gentil una pista para sacarme de este problema que me tiene frenado desde hace dias!. Gracias

Comment: ¿`manager.getElements()` devuelve directamente el arreglo o devuelve una promesa? ¿qué ocurre si en lugar de mandar el objeto simple escribes directamente el arreglo en el _emit_?